# Как передать параметры в функцию

Tags: jquery

Допустим есть функция

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.myclass').click(function(){
    }
   });
```

которая вешается на блоки, скажем, с информацией по товару.
Как в эту функцию передать параметр, например код товара? Раньше на чистом js прописывал в каждый блок событие onmouseclick="" и из php подставлял нужный параметр.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Можно назначать параметр как атрибут элемента, например `data-parameter`

```
<div class="myclass" data-parameter="test parameter">contents</div>
```

и затем в jquery читать его:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.myclass').click(function(){
        console.log(this.getAttribute("data-parameter"));
    });
   });
```

Comment: А можно и так: console.log(this.data('parametr));

Comment: Хорошим тоном при использовании jQuery считается писать $(this).param('data-parameter').

Comment: @SoWa, в функцию передается уже jquery объект, поэтому оборачивать еще раз в $() не стоит. 

Да и .param() делает совсем другое, она преобразует объект в пригодный для передачи через GET. http://jquery.page2page.ru/index.php5/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8A%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2_%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F_%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D0%B2_url

правка: первым пунктом я ошибся, передается не jquery объект.

Comment: Хорошим тоном считается использовать методы по назначению. Если используем [HTML5 Custom Data Attributes ](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/elements.html#custom-data-attribute), то работаем с соответствующим [$.data()](http://api.jquery.com/data/). Плюсую комментарий @caravaneer.

Comment: Ооой, простите, друзья, я с param вще напутал, извиняюсь, там должен быть prop

Comment: Народ, дайте уже работающий грамотный ответ

Comment: вам его уже дали

Answer (score 2):

В jQuery когда мы вешаем любое событие на элемент практически очень редко нам приходиться дать параметры в функцию обработчик. Но в jQuery реализовано все это, оно называется [.data()](https://api.jquery.com/data/)
Вот простой пример где мы даем `data` параметры в функцию обработчик клика на элемент.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.test_func').each(function(key, val){
        $(val).click(function(event){
            console.log($(this).data('param'));
        });
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="test_func" data-param="test param 1">test content</div>
<div class="test_func" data-param="test param 2">test content</div>
```

В jQuery есть функция .data() и с помощью него мы взяли атрибут тега `html` который написано так `data-param`, здесь главное начальное имя атрибута который мы должны написать так `data-` а остальная часть уже имя которым мы в jQuery взяли значение атрибута.

Comment: что делать если элементов с классом `test_func` несколько и у каждого должен быть _свой_ `param1` и `param2`?

Comment: можете по пунктам задать вопрос и дать нам кусок кода который вы хотите реализовать, и я отвечу на ваш вопрос.

Comment: Я к тому, что твой ответ не отвечает на заданный вопрос. Судя по вопросу у каждого элемента `.myclass` **свой собственный** - код товара, в твоем случае - он _один на все_

Comment: @Grundy  Один нюанс пропустил, сделаю поправку в ответе, и так видно что там уже другой вопрос а не дубликат вопроса.

Comment: _и так видно что там уже другой вопрос а не дубликат вопроса_ - поэтому я и не закрыл дубликатом, и поэтому странно писать тот же самый ответ на _другой_ вопрос.

Comment: @Grundy У нас у всех бывают ошибки и недостатки, не кто не идеален)))

Comment: Поэтому стоит ее поправить, отредактировав ответ, либо удалить его, так как он не отвечает на поставленный вопрос

Comment: @Grundy Конечно я вот так и сделал, и мне кажется уже грамотно и решает вопрос.